# How are multiple properties of the same thing properly described?

Tags: adjectives, coordinating-conjunctions

I am sorry but I could not come up with a better way of describing what I am trying to achieve in this sentence:

> As such, their creation should follow a rationale and their interpretation be intuitive

My question specifically is whether there ought to be `should be`, just `be` or nothing (or something entirely different) between *interpretation* and *intuitive*.

Also, is there a name for this specific grammatical pattern/a better way of describing what I am trying to accomplish in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you’re aiming for a type of [linguistic ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

The problem here is that you don’t have the parallel structure necessary to play that game. See if you can rewrite your content to work. Here’s an example based on the ellipsis type *gapping*:

> Gapping occurs in coordinate structures. Redundant material that is
> present in the immediately preceding clause can be “gapped” . . .
>
> *John can play the guitar, and Mary <sub>can play</sub> the violin.*

In your case, the sentence might look like this:

> *As such, their creation should be rationale-based and their interpretation <sub>should be</sub> intuitive.*

There are other elliptical structures that, with a rewrite, might work too.

And you can always skip the ellipsis:

> *As such, their creation should follow a rationale and their interpretation should be intuitive.*